# How to add new record to another table created within the same model on Rails console?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a model using this command

```
rails g model UserPost postId:string postDesc:string
```

than after I created another table with

```
rails g migration CreateUser name:string email:string
```

So, running `rails console`, I was only able to add records on `user_posts` table with for example

```
user=UserPost.create(post_id:"My Post", post_desc:"This is my post")
```

My question is to know how to add new records on `user` table?
With Sql, this is done using `table_name` as

```
INSERT INTO TABLE user_posts values("My Post", "This is my post")
```

and

```
INSERT INTO TABLE users values("my_name", "my_email")
```

but on Rails, I think it uses model's name.

Note: `rake db:migrate` has been run at its specific time.

Comment: Is you want to insert data in user model during UserPost model creation??

Comment: not inserting during UserPost model creation, instead after its creation and addition of users table in the same model  on rails console, of course is me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should change table name of `user` table to `users` since it's convenient. Then you should create a model for your users table: `rails g model user`. Then you will be able to add records to users table as you adding records to the posts: `User.create(name: 'my_name', email: 'my_email')`.

UPD
You should have a rails model to each db table unless it's a join table

Comment: Oh sorry! it's just a typo. I understand that; I'd just like to know whether it is possible to add a record to that table in that case, as in Sql example provided.

Comment: If you have created a model ```User```, then you can do it like ```User.create(name: 'my_name', email: 'my_email')```

Comment: that's pretty easy! so do you mean that it is not possible to add record on users table unless I create an appropriate model for it?

Comment: Yes :) You should always have a model to each table in db unless it's a join table